# Hide overflow elements in angular list

Tags: html, angular, dom, overflow

I'm trying to hide overflow elements in the list. Example is present below. 
[image]

I'd like to hide elements that do not fit inside the red container, but i dont have any idea how to do that and how to count them.

I tried use ViewChild and ViewChildren, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

One time I had implemented a pagination for cards, and there I need to show the number of cards which fits inside the available width for handling the responsive mode. That task was quite easy comparing this as the card width was same.

I guess you can try, registering the `window:resize` listener and then calculate the available width and width of cards to be shown and show only which gets fits.